# ASP.Net Mono HTTPHandler stops processing a request unexpectedly

Tags: asp.net, mono, handler

I am not sure if the question is clear enough but here is the problem, I ran this code in a generic handler in a ASP.Net Mono project, no matter how many times I run this code the loop never crosses the 140000 mark. The loop stops anywhere between 1200000 to 1400000.

```
context.Response.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString()+" MilliSec:"+ DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString() + "<br/>");
            for (int i = 0; i <= 1083646; i++)
            {
                context.Response.Write("C#/.Net on Windows:" + i.ToString());
                context.Response.Flush();
            }
            context.Response.Write("<br/>"+DateTime.Now.ToString() + " MilliSec:" + DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString() + "<br/>");
```

It just prints anywhere between 1200000 and 1400000 and then the response just ends without any exceptions.

I am running Windows 7 x64, Mono 2.10.9 On XSP 2.0 webserver

I am not sure if it the issue is with XSP or with the CLR since it has performance issues handling strings and memory reclamation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend using Mono in Windows, it has a lower level of quality compared to other platforms (Linux/Mac), because in Windows there is already the .NET framework.